# Notable differences if all stars would disappear except the Sun

Tags: star, life, habitable-zone

I am not an astronomy expert, but as of today, all other stars than the Sun have little to no effect on life on Earth. So I was thinking, would there be any differences for the Earth **at all** if all stars would disappear except the Sun?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to tell which way is north at night.

Comment: Well it's 2015, a compass will do the  job

Comment: Oh yeah, I hadn't thought of that... not.

Comment: Pictures of the aurora would be less interesting. The internet would no longer be infested with shots of the milky way over eg Baffin bay. The planets, and a few asterods, would stand out a lot clearer. We'd actually be able to see a goodly number of the vast number of satellites and bits of space junk that orbit the earth. It'd be easier to set a camera to take a pic whenever a meteor flashes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main things we should look at here, because there are two main ways these distant stars can affect us: light and gravity.

**Light**

If all the stars in the universe disappeared (besides the Sun), the most of the luminous objects in the universe would simply vanish. There would still be objects emitting radiation - stellar remnants, accretion disks, etc. - but the notable sources of light would be gone.

Would this be an issue? I can't give you any numbers, but I would assume that there wouldn't be much of a difference. Night/day cycles would continue as normal, because the rotation of the Earth also would not be affected. The behavior of [stoma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoma) in plants should remain the same, as should all the other natural rituals of life.

**Gravity**

This is where I'm slightly more concerned. Stars have mass, and so they influence other objects with gravity. There are varying estimates of how much of the Milky Way is made up of stars. For example, [McMillan (2011)](http://mnras.oxfordjournals.org/content/414/3/2446.full.pdf) estimated the stellar mass of the Milky Way to be about 6.43$\times$10<sup>10</sup> solar masses, while the virial (total) mass was estimated to be about 1.26$\times$10<sup>12</sup> solar masses.

The extra matter consists of gas, dust, planets, stellar remnants, and, of course, dark matter (a lot of it). The mass of the Milky Way would be reduced by about 5% - not a terrible amount, but certainly non-negligible. I don't know how this would impact the motion of the Solar System; detailed simulations based on density models would be needed.

However, any effects from stars wouldn't reach us any time soon. Light and gravity both travel at the speed of light, so we'd have at least four years before we started seeing the effects (4 light-years is the distance to the nearest star, Proxima Centauri). We wouldn't feel the effects from the rest of the galaxy for many more years.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean if they disappeared now, or disappeared at some arbitrary time?

If the latter, then I would say that if they had disappeared more than a few thousand years ago, we might still be living in mud huts. The movement of stars and planets in the heavens motivated many of the ancient scholars and led directly to things like Newton's laws and a theory of gravity.

If the former, no immediate physical consequences, but - I would say a worldwide panic and financial meltdown for starters.

Comment: And if they'd disappeared billions of years ago, maybe Earth would be lifeless. Not that I'm a fan of "panspermia", but you never know.

Answer (score 1):

One example: there might be some effects on animal migration, as migrating species have been shown to respond to star patterns in a planetarium in various experiments over the years.

Even dung beetles were found to respond to the "stripe" of the milky way across the sky, in an experiment publicised a few years ago.  This was not for long distance migration by the way, but for moving in a straight line for a short distance when a food source is found.

[BBC news story about dung beetles](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science-environment-21150721)

[Paper about dung beetles](http://web.mnstate.edu/wisenden/AnBeh13%20Paper%205%20Dacke%20et%20al%202013.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you mean to say: if the stars would disappear *right now*, but in case you meant to say *if there had never been stars*, here is an additional answer.

Without stars human development would have followed completely different paths, and there's no way to know where we would have ended by now.

Probably as long as human beings developed some form of intelligence (whatever that may be), and especially its components curiosity and inquisitiveness, the movements of the stars will have puzzled them: what are these scintillating, unreachable pinpricks of light that follow regular (or sort-of-regular) patterns?

This has influenced religion, philosophy, and science in no small part: stories about deities in the sky, measurement of time during the year, navigation directions, all astronomical knowledge (probably including relativity), etc...